# Function chain factory in TypeScript preserving input/output types?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, yield

Consider this pyramid code:

```js
/**
 * @template T, U
 * @param {T} data
 * @param {(data: T) => Promise<U>} fn
 */
function makeNexter(data, fn) {
  return {
    data,
    next: async () => fn(data),
  };
}

return makeNexter({}, async (data) => {

  return makeNexter({ ...data, a: 3 }, async (data) => {

    return makeNexter({ ...data, b: 'hi' }, async (data) => {

    });

  });

});
```

Is there a way to make a function that takes an indefinite number of these functions in an array, and applies the results of each to the next function in order, while preserving type information, so that each data parameter on the inner function has properly inferred types?

Basically I'm trying to make this code flat instead of a pyramid, while preserving type information in each parameter.

Another way to look at this is that I'm trying to make a kind of generator function whose yielded types don't need to be asserted/filtered at each step (out of the type union that function generators normally return), but rather are definitely known at each step because they're always passed linearly.

In other words, is it possible to create this function in TypeScript with proper type information?

```js
/** @type {???} */
return makeNexters({}, [
  async (data) => {
    return { ...data, a: 3 };
  },
  async (data) => {
    return { ...data, b: 'hi' };
  },
  async (data) => {
    // data here should have type:
    //   {
    //     b: string;
    //     a: number;
    //   }
  },
]);
```

See also my feature request in TypeScript issues: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you will be able to come up with a solution in which the compiler infers types the way you want without any extra work when calling the function.

There is a design limitation of TypeScript, highlighted in [microsoft/TypeScript#38872](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872), where the compiler cannot simultaneously infer generic type parameters and the contextual type for a callback parameter when these inferences would need to be dependent on each other.  When you call:

```
return makeNexters({}, [
  async (data) => { return { ...data, a: 3 };  },
  async (data) => { return { ...data, b: 'hi' }; },
  async (data) => {},
])
```

you are presumably asking the compiler to use `{}` to infer some generic type parameter (or piece of one), which will be used to infer the type of the first `data` callback parameter, which will then be used to infer some generic type parameter (or piece of one), which will then be used to infer the type of the second `data` callback parameter, et cetera.  But the compiler only performs a limited number of type inference phases, and will give up after inferring possibly the first one or two of these.

---

Conceptually I'd express the type of `makeNexters()` to be something like this:

```
type Idx<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never

declare function makeNexters<T, R extends readonly any[]>(
  init: T, next: readonly [...{ [K in keyof R]: (data: Idx<[T, ...R], K>) => Promise<R[K]> }]
): void;
```

Where I'm saying that the `init` parameter is of generic type `T`, and the `next` parameter is of a type that [maps over a tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) `R`.  Each element in `next` should be a function that accepts a `data` parameter of the "previous" element in `R` (except for the very first one which accepts it from `T`), and returns a `Promise` to the "current" element in `R`.

(I'm not even worried about the fact that this thing returns `void`. If the inference worked then I'd worry about expressing the return type in terms of `T` and `R`, but for now that's not the point of this)

And this function *will* work, but not in a way that infers the way you'd like. You can essentially either give up on contextual inference of callback parameters and get pretty good generic type inference:

```
makeNexters({}, [
  async (data: {}) => { return { ...data, a: 3 }; },
  async (data: { a: number }) => { return { ...data, b: 'hi' }; },
  async (data: { a: number, b: string }) => { },
]);
/*function makeNexters<{}, [{ a: number; }, { b: string; a: number; }, void]>() */
```

Or you can give up on generic type inference and get pretty good contextual type inference for callback parameters:

```
makeNexters<{}, [{ a: number }, { b: string, a: number }, void]>({}, [
  async (data) => { return { ...data, a: 3 }; },
  async (data) => { return { ...data, b: 'hi' }; },
  async (data) => { }
]);
```

If you try to get both the compiler gives you neither: it will infer `any` all over the place:

```
makeNexters({}, [
  async (data) => { return { ...data, a: 3 }; },
  async (data) => { return { ...data, b: 'hi' }; },
  async (data) => { }
]);
/* function makeNexters<{}, [any, any, void]>*/
```

And presumably any code where you have to write out the type `{b: string, a: number}` is defeating the purpose of this chaining function.

---

Before giving up entirely I'd suggest that you consider changing your approach to one which works by making a function that returns another function.  Essentially this is a form of [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), where instead of creating the "nexter" all at once, where the chain is represented by a single array, you do it in stages where each link in the chain is forged by a function call. These calls are not nested, so it's not a "pyramid" anymore.  You'd use it like this:

```
const p = makeNexterChain({})
  .and(async data => ({ ...data, a: 3 }))
  .and(async data => ({ ...data, b: "hi" }))
  .done
```

And the `p` that was produced would be of type

```
/*const p: {
    data: {};
    next: () => Promise<{
        data: {
            a: number;
        };
        next: () => Promise<{
            data: {
                b: string;
                a: number;
            };
            next: () => Promise<void>;
        }>;
    }>;
} */
```

which is the same as you'd get with your original nested version.

The implementation of `makeNexterChain()` is outside the scope of this question, because it seems you are asking about the types and not the runtime behavior.  You could presumably implement `makeNexterChain()` with appropriate use of the `then()` method of various promises.

Anyway, here's the typings for `makeNexterChain()`:

```
type Nexter<R extends any[]> = R extends [infer H, ...infer T] ? {
  data: H
  next: () => Promise<Nexter<T>>
} : void

type Last<T> = T extends [...infer F, infer L] ? L : never

interface NexterChain<R extends any[]> {
  and<U>(cb: (data: Last<R>) => Promise<U>): NexterChain<[...R, U]>
  done: Nexter<R>
}
declare function makeNexterChain<T>(init: T): NexterChain<[T]>;
```

Essentially you want `makeNexterChain()` to take an initial element of type `T`, and return a `NexterChain<[T]>`.  Each `NexterChain<R>` (where `R` is a tuple type) has an `and()` method to append a new type onto the end of `R`, and a `done()` method which returns a `Nexter<R>`.  A `Nexter<R>` has a `data` property whose type is the first element of `R`, and a `next()` method of no arguments, which produces a `Promise` of a new `Nexter<T>` where `T` the same as `R` with the first element removed.  Oh and when it gets to the end you get `void`.

You can see that here that type inference works very well indeed.  At each step, the compiler knows what the `data` callback parameter will be, and you don't need to manually specify any generic parameters or manually annotate any callback parameters.  Hopefully you can use a solution like this which works with instead of against TypeScript's type inference capabilities.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.2#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-H4GCdoENJLKAkBQKeEiDI4pAUNQyEBLgBAOAcJGpBETDqgAEhgDR0eqKD8JwmQXMiQgMRcIgkKU5JdD0fQDPhqDYNgUijIIuazHAMg4dAAAy4LAJJ+CsERzjUOkGSsXWABiGCGVAKkceZckiOI0hSBEVhMMo8jQPhADCWLKBEhHUS4ZEjFx0oUEgACqwTyIalrmepgzYMJ3S9P0oVxUI7med5+mNBgIWBNxBgQKlYaxTJsgKCoahQFBgawfsTIeV5ZCSUEERRDEUx4WG9UZex2BHvIBhOlAYBaaWnXpWQLItBcaS+HAQQyjcyKescX4Pn84otFNYQzRQ839kte4rWOKIGkIABEOJnRqW1CkkEAyGs-VkINYAKhcYQ8RSixhGEAnRLc8WiUlgU-aDn0g6DkMTracbfVDQLvZDf1CZ6ImJQMEPwx98ofIjWOg42qbpnj+PSjGbZw6TEok1DyMA6jCViUgna9TTYys6Doys7JNJAA)

Comment: I was following you completely, right up until the type definition of `makeNexterChain`, at which point it seemed overly complicated. Couldn't the function be typed in such a way that it only needs a single type, with two types, T for input and U for output, but returns a recursive type whose output U becomes an input T, without three types each with their own generics?

Comment: A `NexterChain<R>` is a builder that makes a `Nexter<R>`, each of which needs to keep track of the tuple of types `R` that make up the full chain.  Each call to `and()` needs to produce a `NexterChain` that appends a type to the *end* of `R`, and then when you access `done` it needs to produce the recursive `Nexter` type that starts at the *beginning* of `R`.  I don't see how to eliminate the tuple chain into a single input-output relationship.  You can eliminate `Last` which is just a utility type like [so](https://tsplay.dev/N9ApjN), but I'm not seeing anything much simpler than that.

Comment: It might not matter, but I just wanted to make sure that `makeNexterChain()` above was indeed implementable.  My implementation looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nl0xXN), and it seems to work as intended.